# babylon.js: object depth rendering artefacts

Tags: depth, babylonjs, visual-glitch

I have lots of visual artefacts when you are trying to rotate scene.
Pretty sure that it's a depth test issue.

[image]

In c++/openFrameworks this thing could be solved by global method ofEnableDepthTest().

Using PBRMaterials with .disableDepthWrite = false and .alphaMode = 2;

Comment: Something wrong with PBRMaterials, because it works fine with StandardMaterials

Comment: More specific with .apha less than 1.0

Comment: If this works with std material then we have a bug. Can you post a repro on your topic on bjs forum?

Comment: Why do you need alphamode=2?

Comment: It's the same with StandardMaterial
https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/issues/2550#issuecomment-316448912